# Apache Airflow scheduler not running workers on its own

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, airflow

I am currently trying Apache Airflow on my system (Ubuntu 18) and I set it up with postgreSQL and RabbitMQ to use the CeleryExecutor.

I run `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` on separate consoles, but the scheduler is only putting tasks as queued but no worker is actually running them.

I tried opening a different terminal and run `airflow worker` on its own and that seemed to do the trick.

Now the scheduler puts tasks on a queue and the worker I ran manually actually executes them.

As I have read, that should not be the case. The scheduler should run the workers on its own right? What could I do to make this work?

I have checked the logs from the consoles and I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. If you look at the docs for [airflow worker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#worker), it is specifically to bring up a *Celery* worker when you're using the `CeleryExecutor`, while the other executors do not require a separate process for tasks to run.

- `LocalExecutor`: uses multiprocessing to run tasks within the scheduler.
- `SequentialExecutor`: just runs one task at a time so that happens within the scheduler as well.
- `CeleryExecutor`: scales out by having N workers, so having it as a separate command lets you run a worker on as many machines as you'd like.
- `KubernetesExecutor`: I imagine talks to your Kubernetes cluster to tell it to run tasks.